# log counter in java Logger

Tags: java, logging

I'm using `java.util.logging.Logger` for logging various messages, on different levels (eg. by methods `.fine()`, `.finer()`, `.info()`, `.warning()`). I'd like to get info how many messages on each level were logged. Is it possible **without** writting my own class like:

```
public class MyLogger extends Logger
{
   int infoCounter = 0;

   @Override
   public void info(String msg)
   {
      super.info(msg);
      infoCounter++; 
   }
}
```

Comment: This example code is not quite thread safe, which is very important for a logger.

Comment: @KZhang I don't intend to use that `MyLogger` class (hope there's something easier and better) and my aplication isn't multi-threaded, but even if I'd like it to - what's the problem? I'll just put code inside `synchronized` brackets and problem solved.

Comment: Yes. It will become thread safe after your synchronized protect the part of this class.

Comment: Small typo: `super(msg)` should be `super.info(msg)`.

Comment: @TJamesBoone You're right, I was writting code just to show concept, I never ran it and that's the source of this typo. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is **no, this is not possible**.
The way you are doing it now is good (once it's synchronized, of course).

There is an alternative: instead of extending Logger, extend java.util.logging.Handler, and then:

1. Override the publish() method
2. Implement flush() and close()
3. Create a method to count messages by Level

   I tried this and tested it, and it worked:

   ```
   import java.util.ArrayList;
   import java.util.List;
   import java.util.logging.Handler;    
   import java.util.logging.Level;
   import java.util.logging.LogRecord;

   public class CountHandler extends Handler {

   List<LogRecord> records = new ArrayList<LogRecord>();

       @Override
       public void publish(LogRecord record) {
           records.add(record);
       }

       public int howMany(Level level) {
           int howMany = 0;
           for(LogRecord record : records) {
               if (record.getLevel().intValue() == level.intValue()) {
                   howMany++;
               }
           }
           return howMany;
       }

       @Override
       public void flush() {

       }

       @Override
       public void close() throws SecurityException {

       }

   }
   ```

The advantage to this is that you don't have to override methods for every single Level.  The only thing is that you'll have to add this handler to each of your loggers:

```
CountHandler messageCounter= new CountHandler();
        logger.addHandler(messageCounter);
```

So take it for what it's worth.  Whatever you do, you'll have to write your own class.

Comment: Please excuse the formatting in my answer, where the import statements didn't make it into the code block.  I've tried to fix it but the editor is buggy.